# Routing error with certains emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Rails routes wont accept a route if the email is of the form `amits321321@sma.com` but this comes out fine `amit321321@sma.com` (notice the s).

Infact any s present makes the system go haywire...

this is the constraint in the route...

```
:constraints => { :email => /([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regexp:

```
/^([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})$/i
```

Comment: Its from devise - a famous authentication system.

Comment: if i am not wrong, rails does not accept anchor when used with phusion(i haven't used nethng else so not sure about others)... btw this didn't help either